# ¿free funciona dentro de otra función?

Tags: c, null

El punto es, si tengo una función que recibe un puntero inicializado con memoria dinamica y dentro de ella se utiliza free, ¿la memoria continúa liberada al salir de la función? pregunto esto debido a el asunto del paso de parámetros por valor y por referencia.
Otro problema seria: si dentro de la función asigno NULL al puntero ¿Conserva este valor al salir de la función?
Funcionaria como es deseado este código:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void func(int *ptr){
    free(ptr);
    ptr = NULL;
}

int main(){
    int *numero =  (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*10000); 
    func(numero); 
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > ¿free funciona dentro de otra función?

Respuesta: **Si.**

> > ¿la memoria continúa liberada al salir de la función?

Respuesta: **Si.**

Cuando se ejecuta esta instrucción:

```c
func(numero);
```

Se le pasa al parámetro el contenido del puntero, es decir, a lo que apunta `numero`, que vendría ser la dirección base (del primer elemento) del bloque de memoria reservado con `malloc`.

Posteriormente, cuando se ejecute el bloque de código de la función `func`, la memoria que habías reservado si se va a liberar, debido a que, el parámetro `ptr` apunta hacia la misma dirección que `numero`.

> > si dentro de la función asigno NULL al puntero ¿Conserva este valor al salir de la función?

Respuesta: **No.**

Cuando se invocó la función `func` se pasó por valor, por lo tanto, se está pasando una copia del contenido al parámetro.

Por ende, cuando se ejecute esta línea:

```
ptr = NULL;
```

Le estarás asignando el `NULL` al parámetro `ptr` y como sabrás, cuando la función termine su ejecución, dicho parámetro quedará liberado de memoria, por lo tanto, el puntero que pasaste por valor, siguió apuntando al bloque de memoria que habías reservado anteriormente.

Esto se vuelve peligroso, debido a que, si llegaras a usar el puntero después de la ejecución de `func`, ocurrirá un fallo de segmentación.

**Ejemplo del error:**

```c
int main(){
    int *numero =  (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*10000); 
    func(numero); 
    *numero = 10; //error in runtime
    return 1;
}
```

Al liberar el bloque de memoria ya no le pertenece al programa, por lo tanto, habrá una falla de segmentación si se intenta acceder con el puntero y esto hace que la aplicación termine su ejecución.

Si quieres modificar el contenido del puntero, deberás pasar la dirección de memoria donde se aloje dicho puntero.

**Ejemplo:**

```c
#include<stdio.h>

void func(int **ptr){
    free(*ptr);
    *ptr = NULL;
}

int main(){
    int *numero =  (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*10000); 
    func(&numero);
    printf("is %p", numero);
    return 1;
}
```

El código de la función cambio un poco, ahora tiene como parámetro un puntero doble, en la cual recibe la dirección de memoria del puntero.

Así que cuando se ejecute esta línea:

```c
free(*ptr);
```

Se estará accediendo al contenido del puntero, que vendría ser la dirección base del bloque de memoria que se reservó con `malloc`.

Posteriormente, se ejecuta:

```c
*ptr = NULL;
```

Y esto modificará el contenido del puntero, por lo tanto, valdrá `NULL`.

**Recalco** que en este caso, si se podría prevenir el fallo de segmentación si es que se usa el puntero después de liberar la memoria.

**Ejemplo:**

```c
int main(){
    int *numero =  (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*10000); 
    func(&numero);
    if(numero != NULL)
    {
        *numero = 10;
         printf("Valor inicial: %d\n", *numero);
    }
    return 1;
}
```